# Abort service start

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android app with a service which connects to a peripheral device and listens to its output. The connection to the peripheral is initiated in the service’s `onStartCommand()` method.

Establishing the connection involves several “hopefullies” and may sometimes fail with an exception.

How can I prevent the service from becoming a zombie that’s running but has no connection to monitor? Calling `stopSelf()` from within `onStartCommand()` doesn’t seem to work.

Rough code:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        // connect to device
    } catch (ConnectToDeviceException e) {
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by moving the connection code into an `AsyncTask` and stopping the service from there if the connection fails.

Since `onStartCommand()` runs on the UI thread and connecting to a device can take some time, taking this off the UI thread by putting it in an `AsyncTask` is cleaner anyway.

Simplified code:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    StartupTask startupTask = new StartupTask();
    startupTask.execute();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

private class StartupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean success = true;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // connect to device
        } catch (ConnectToDeviceException e) {
            success = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (!success)
            stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem.  Can you accept your answer to make it obvious the problem was solved?

Comment: Done (there’s a 48-hour waiting period).